# React props show up as undefined at first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that makes an api call based on the data recieved by its props.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        followsUser: null
    }
componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props)
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/check/${this.props.id}`)
    .then(res => this.setState({ followsUser: res.data.follows }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

I call the component in another component like:

```
<FollowButton key={this.state.user.id} id={this.state.user.id} />
```

But in the browser console I get the following error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/check/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

This is what I see in the browser console: 
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtmCg.png)

Comment: Try to add whole Component Code , so we can help you better

Comment: `componentDidMount` runs after the component has been rendered and mounted into the DOM. It renders once before the data is fetched, so you need to handle the case where the `followsUser` is null, or whatever you set the initial value to be.

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(this.props)` in the `componentDidMount` hook?

Comment: The output is as follows: 1. undefined 2. api call is made 3. 2

Comment: Try wrapping api call inside an `if` `if (this.props.id !== undefined)  {... fetch ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

State-setting is an asynchronous operation, so whenever you're intending to act upon data that is somehow derived from state, it's wise to manually safeguard against `undefined` values that might be present before getting updated state.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    followsUser: null
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  // one could write
  //
  // if (this.props.id)
  //
  // but if there's a possibility the id could be 0 (which is falsy),
  // it's safer to explicitly check for undefined.

  if (typeof this.props.id !== 'undefined') {
    axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/check/${this.props.id}`)
      .then(res => this.setState({ followsUser: res.data.follows }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```